# Emacs tramp "args out of range" too often, how to recover connection automatically?

Tags: tramp

I have tramp configured to work automatically with SSH key and all, but I am having this message too often:

> byte-code: Args out of range: #<buffer *tramp/ssh gs*>, 60, 14056

To solve it temporarily I just kill the tramp buffer:

> * *tramp/ssh gs*         9994 Fundamental

In *Buffer List* I apply D and X to kill this buffer.

Then I just keep working, tramp will reconnect automatically when I save. In a matter of 5-30 minutes, the message reappears and I have to kill the tramp buffer again.

How can I have a more fluent working without having to be killing the tramp buffer?

How to recover automatically each time the connection droops?

Comment: You don't say which Tramp version you are using. However, in preparation of the upcoming Tramp 2.3.0 several errors have been fixed, which could also cover the one you've mentioned. Maybe you give it a try, either from the Tramp repository, or end of June, when it has been released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was also reported as Emacs bug 23883, see http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23883 . It has been resolved recently, will appear with next Tramp 2.3.1 and/or Emacs 25.2.